# Get Value Outside a Tag using WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to get a Value outside a tag using Python Webdriver.But i am getting both (inside and outside) values.

[Html codeto scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiMMn.png)

That's what I am doing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.zattini.com.br/roupas/feminino?mi=ztt_hm_fem_cat1_roupas&psn=Banner_BarradeCategorias_1fem&fc=barradecategorias'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

brands = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@qa-automation='search-brand']")

#html = driver.page_source

printf(brands.text)
```

But I am getting :

```
#MO
5
```

And all I want is the "Mo" value. To, after that, get the "5" in another column of the array.

What can I change to get them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a element(/span) as a child element of anchor, it prints all the text.
Try this solution,

```
brands = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@qa-automation='search-brand']")
brandcount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@qa-automation='search-brand']/span")
#html = driver.page_source
print(str(brands.text).strip(brandcount.text).strip('\n'))
print(brandcount.text)
```